# How to find file in the iphone?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am saving my data in the iphone. How could I find the following txt file?

Any idea?

My file is saved in the following directory:

/var/mobile/Applications/366D42D4-5817-4007-831B-1A6EB929AF8E/Documents/Annotation1.txt

My question is how to find txt file already saved in the iphone.

Comment: Is Annotation.txt a folder or a file? It's named like a file but your updated question now asks about it like it is a folder.

Comment: This question turned out to be completely different from the desired goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your device to computer.

Run Xcode.

Open Organizer (Window->Organizer)

Select Devices tab and then select your device on the left side

You should see something like:

MyIpad

- Provisioning Profiles
- Applications
- Console
- Device Logs
- Screenshots

select Applications

select application that saved the data you're interested in

on the bottom line click download and save the archived file to the desktop

you can open archived file with right-click and "Show Package Contents"

Answer (score 3):

You get access to the Documents directory by doing:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

You would then append the filename:

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Annotation1.txt"];
```

That gives you the path to the file. But if you didn't know this, how did you save the file to begin with?

Edit: It turns out the OP wants to provide access to the files in the Documents directory via iTunes. This is done by adding the "Application supports iTunes file sharing" key to the Info.plist. The value should be a boolean with a value of YES.

Comment: I know how to write and read data. I would like to see these folders.

Comment: @user1724168 See what folders? Your question asked how to find the file in the stated directory. Now you are asking about some folders. Sorry, your question isn't clear.

Comment: I am sorry.My fault. How could I find the folder?

Comment: What folder? Do you mean the Documents folder? The first two lines of code I posted give you access to the Documents folder.

Comment: I would like to see folder, and save it on my desktop and process them with scientific language (matlab).

Comment: @user1724168 You keep saying folder. What folder? Where do you want to see this folder? You are not being clear at all. Are you talking about being able to share the Documents folder in iTunes so the user can access the files from iTunes?

Comment: yes,sir. I would like to see this file in iTunes. However, I could not able to see this file in iTunes?

Comment: This is a completely different topic than you asked in your original question. To allow someone to see the files in an app's Documents directory you need to enable file sharing by adding a value to the Info.plist. Add the "Application supports iTunes file sharing" key to the Info.plist. Make it a boolean value and set it to YES.